# Writing "W" letter with c

Tags: c

Receiving the height information from the user and printing the letter W with *** (3 stars).This is my homework but i need to improve this code.

I did something like that with google but it always showing me same height. I want someone to enter a number and change the height. (i do not know why the site not accepting #include <stdio.h> as a code. Sorry for that.)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    
    int a,b,c,d,e;
    
    
    for(a=0;a<=11;a++)
    {   
        for(b=0;b<=2;b++){
            printf("*");
        }
        
        
        for(c=10;c>=a;c--)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        
        
        
            for(b=0;b<=2;b++){
            printf("*");
        }
        
        
        for(d=1;d<=a;d++)
        {
        printf("  ");
        }
        
            for(b=0;b<=2;b++){
            printf("*");
        }
        
        
        for(e=10;e>=a;e--)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for(b=0;b<=2;b++){
            printf("*");
        }
        
    printf("\n");   
    }   
    
}
```

Comment: To me its not clear yet what you want to achieve by looking at your description and your code. Can you show an example maybe? Also, you can use the same variable for all the inner `for` loops. No need to have a unique one in each.

Comment: i need to put scanf this code.

Comment: @Agah No, you certainly do not need `scanf`.  If you want to take user input as a parameter, take it from the second argument to main.  If you insist on reading the parameter from the input stream, there are many better alternatives to scanf.  `scanf` is the last thing you should even consider.  The only alternative that is worse is `gets`, and that should not even be considered.

Comment: This is more a question of [cartesian geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system) than of C programming. Learn about [Bézier curves](https://web.mit.edu/hyperbook/Patrikalakis-Maekawa-Cho/node13.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

 int main()
 {

   int a,b,c,d,e,height;
   printf("Enter a height : ");  // print "Enter a height :"
   scanf("%d",&height);          // ask to user how much height
   height--;
   for(a=0;a<=height;a++)   //a<=11       
    {   
      for(b=0;b<=2;b++){
       printf("*");
     }


  for(c=0;c<height-a;c++)
{
    printf(" ");
}



    for(b=0;b<=2;b++){
    printf("*");
}


for(d=1;d<=a;d++)
{
printf("  ");
}

    for(b=0;b<=2;b++){
    printf("*");
}


for(e=0;e<height-a;e++)
{
    printf(" ");
}
for(b=0;b<=2;b++){
    printf("*");
}

printf("\n");   
}   

}
```

Comment: i tried this too but when you enter Numbers less than 10. it is not working correctly